# Optimize query - mysql

Tags: mysql, optimization, myisam

i try to optimize my query because it takes 3.5 seconds and its too long.
this is my query:

```
SELECT
`products`.*,
IFNULL(SUM(`products_uses`.`quantity`),0) as `usesQuantity`,
IF((`products`.`productQuantity` - IFNULL(SUM(`products_uses`.`quantity`),0)) > 0, (`products`.`productQuantity` - IFNULL(SUM(`products_uses`.`quantity`),0)), 0) AS `totalUses`
FROM `products`
LEFT JOIN `products_uses` ON `products`.`id` = `products_uses`.`productId`
WHERE `products`.`nurseForm` = 1
GROUP BY `products`.`id`
ORDER BY `products`.`fav` DESC, `products`.`productName` ASC
```

i tried to optimize with variables but nothing changed:

```
SELECT
`products`.*,
@usesQuantity := IFNULL(SUM(`products_uses`.`quantity`),0) as `usesQuantity`,
IF((`products`.`productQuantity` - @usesQuantity) > 0, (`products`.`productQuantity` - @usesQuantity), 0) AS `totalUses`
FROM `products`
LEFT JOIN `products_uses` ON `products`.`id` = `products_uses`.`productId`
WHERE `products`.`nurseForm` = 1
GROUP BY `products`.`id`
ORDER BY `products`.`fav` DESC, `products`.`productName` ASC
```

this query
 sum how much quantity used each product - `IFNULL(SUM(`products_uses`.`quantity`),0)`
,
how much uses each product -

```
IF((`products`.`productQuantity` - IFNULL(SUM(`products_uses`.`quantity`),0)) > 0, (`products`.`productQuantity` - IFNULL(SUM(`products_uses`.`quantity`),0)), 0)
```

i tried to changed structure of the tables to myISAM and InnoDB nothing changed.
what can i do to optimize this query? 
tnx

Comment: 1.  Check query plan with [explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html)  

2.  Identify longer running part  

3, try to optimize it (how depends on explain results)  

4. If time is not ok after optimizing it, back to 1  

  
As a first approach I'd add products.productQuantity IS NOT NULL on WHERE clause, this avoids retrieving them and executing ifnull

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that introducing user variables will change much.  But stategically adding indices on your two tables might help.  Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD INDEX nurse_index (nurseForm);
ALTER TABLE products_uses ADD INDEX product_index (productId);
```

The first index, on the `products.nurseForm` column, might help the `WHERE` clause.  In particular, this index would be a big help if only a few records match.

The second index, on `products_uses.productId`, might help the join go faster.  Again, this would depend on how large your tables are.

You may also run `EXPLAIN` to see if any other bottlenecks stand out.

Answer (score 0):

Providing `SHOW CREATE TABLE` would help.  Meanwhile, I will guess.

This may (or may not) help.  It attempts to do the summing without hauling all the columns of `products` around.  It avoids the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT  p2.*,
        IFNULL(x.usesQuantity, 0) as `usesQuantity`,
        GREATEST(p2.`productQuantity` - IFNULL(x.usesQuantity), 0) AS `totalUses`
    FROM  `products` AS p2
    LEFT JOIN  
        ( SELECT  p.id AS xid,
                  SUM(pu.quantity) as `usesQuantity`
            FROM  products_uses AS pu
            JOIN  products AS p  ON p.id = pu.productId
            WHERE  p.nurseForm = 1 
        ) AS x  ON x.xid = p2.id
    ORDER BY  p2.`fav` DESC,
              p2.`productName` ASC
```

These indexes should help:

```
products:  INDEX(nurseForm, id)
products:  PRIMARY KEY(id)  -- I am assuming this??
products_uses:  INDEX(productId, quantity)
```

If `LEFT` were unnecessary there would be other optimizations.

MySQL 5.6 would help with the subquery.
MySQL 8.0 could help with the `ORDER BY`, meanwhile, a sort is required due to the mixture of `DESC` and `ASC`.